# Mysql: Obtain the largest number of occurences of a city in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has some data and corresponding city, state. I would like to see the largest number of occurences of a city in a particular state. Say if there are 100 occurences of Denver,CO and 10 occurences of Boulder,CO, I would like to see only Denver, since that's the largest number.  I tried the following, but it lists all other cities too:

```
select state, city, count(city) 
from tab12 
group by city 
order by state, count(city);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT state, city, max(cnt)
FROM
(select state, city, count(city) as cnt
 from tab12 group by city order by state, count(city))
order by state
```

If you want to cover also cases in which you might have cities with the same frequency:

```
SELECT state, city, count(*) cnt 
FROM cities GROUP BY state,city  
HAVING cnt = (SELECT max(cnt) 
              FROM 
              (SELECT count(*) cnt FROM cities group by state,city) as tbl) 
ORDER BY state;
```

Comment: As it is this won't work if there are cities with the same name in multiple states

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(
    SELECT city,state,COUNT(1) citycount
    FROM tab12 GROUP BY state,city
) A INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT state,MAX(citycount) citycount FROM
    (SELECT state,city,COUNT(1) citycount
    FROM tab12 GROUP BY state,city) C
) B
USING (state,citycount)
ORDER BY A.state,A.city;
```

This query should work for states that have multiple cities with the same count.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, off the top of my head:

```
select state as thestate, city as thecity, count(*) as thecount
from tab12
group by state, city
having thecount = (
  select max(subcnt)
  from(
    select count(*) as subcnt
    from tab12 sub
    where sub.state = thestate
    group by sub.city
  )
)
```

Note that in the case of a tie, this will return every city that is tied fro the highest count.